# empty page when plotting a network graph using d3Network package

Tags: r

I'm trying to plot a network graph using the `d3Network` package. I tried organizing the data to match the instructions as they appear on the [package website](http://christophergandrud.github.io/d3Network/) (and help page), but I still get a blank web page. Can anyone spot what I'm doing wrong?

```
library(d3Network)

g.top3000 <- structure(list(from = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 5L), .Label = c("afghanistan", "attack", 
"people", "pres_bush", "taliban"), class = "factor"), to = structure(c(4L, 
1L, 5L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 5L, 2L, 3L, 5L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("people", 
"taliban", "united_states", "attack", "pres_bush"), class = "factor"), 
    weight = c(4, 3, 2, 6, 5, 5, 2, 3, 6, 1, 1, 5, 2, 4, 4)), .Names = c("from", 
"to", "weight"), row.names = c(NA, -15L), class = "data.frame")

top3000.nodes <- structure(list(name = structure(1:5, .Label = c("afghanistan", 
"attack", "people", "pres_bush", "taliban"), class = "factor"), 
    id = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2)), .Names = c("name", "id"), row.names = c(NA, 
-5L), class = "data.frame")

d3ForceNetwork(Links = g.top3000, Nodes = top3000.nodes, Source = "from", Target = "to",
Value = "weight", NodeID = "name", Group = "id", width = 800, height = 400, opacity = 0.9,
   file = "projekt2_terror_news_force.html")
```

Plotting a simple graph works just fine

```
d3SimpleNetwork(g.top3000, width = 800, height = 400, fontsize = 12, linkDistance = 200,
   file = "projekt2_terror_news.html")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because

1. No entry of "united status" in the node list.
2. You may need to use numeric index instead of node name.

---

```
# add entry "united status"
top3000.nodes <- rbind(top3000.nodes, data.frame(name = "united_states", id = 3))

# from name to index
g.top3000$from2 <- sapply(as.character(g.top3000$from), function(x) which(x == top3000.nodes$name))-1
g.top3000$to2 <- sapply(as.character(g.top3000$to), function(x) {
    i <- which(x == top3000.nodes$name)
    if (length(i)) i else NA
    }) -1

# use indices in "from2" and "to2"
d3ForceNetwork(Links = g.top3000, Nodes = top3000.nodes, Source = "from2", Target = "to2",
Value = "weight", NodeID = "name", Group = "id", width = 800, height = 400, opacity = 0.4,
   file = "projekt2_terror_news_force.html", linkDistance = 200)
```

[image]