# Won't generate d3network plot more than once

Tags: r

I'm trying to generate a random network in r to be displayed as a d3Network plot with the intention of eventually implementing it in shiny.  However after first running the code and creating a plot, if I run the code again after altering some parameter such as opacity it only generates a blank html page:

```
devtools::source_gist(9112634)
package(c("tnet", "d3Network"))

id<-1:50
group<-sample(1:10, 50, T)
nodes<-cbind(id, group)
links<-rg_w(nodes = 50, arcs = 0.005, weights = 1:4, directed = FALSE)
library(d3Network)
nodes<-data.frame(nodes)
d3ForceNetwork(Links=links, Nodes=nodes, Source="i", Target="j", Value="w", NodeID="id", Group="group", opacity=0.8, file="Test.visual.html")
```

I've already looked over the following stackoverflow [entry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17701043/empty-page-when-plotting-a-network-graph-using-d3network-package), but neither of the solutions seem to work as I'm using numeric ids and don't notice any typos.  I've also tried other methods of randomly generating the network, but that didn't seem to solve the problem.  Also when I implement the plot in shiny the same error occurs once I've created the app once it will not generate the display a second time.  Also when I run the the simple network the plot works repeatedly:

```
d3SimpleNetwork(links, width = 800, height = 400, fontsize = 12, linkDistance = 200, file = "Test.visual.simple.html")
```

Any help or guidance would be much appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by running the code again? In the same session? Generating the same file (Test.visual.html)? I have ran your code twice and the file looks OK to me.

Comment: I should have been clearer @ddiez it is after I alter a parameter such as opacity or value.  I've edited the original question to clarify.

Comment: Having a hard time replicating this, my Test.visual.html is being updated each time I re run the `d3ForceNetwork` command with a different opacity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure it really solves the problem, but the issue is addressed here: https://github.com/christophergandrud/networkD3/issues/5.   Basically the issue is that the source/target numbering doesn't begin from 0 - 1 always.